# How to attach mochawesome report as email attachment via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cypress, mochawesome

How to attach mochawesome report [Cypress] as email attachment via Jenkins Pipeline script

Comment: 2) How to sent console output via pipeline script via email body

Comment: Are you able to use the [Email extension plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/)?